# Refatoração de uma classe java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, mvc, classes, refatoração

Tenho uma classe Java que contem 1756 linhas(obviamente não é tudo código, tem linhas em branco, muitos comentários e algum código comentado para o caso de ser necessário no futuro)

Estou a implementar a estrutura `MVC` e esta classe pertence ao controlo.

Esta classe é responsável por:

- gerir clientes( comunicação com os cliente, guardar quem está conectado, enviar informação para eles, saber quem saiu etc)
- buscar dados a um webservice e a uma base de dados(sincronizadamente)
- Processar esses dados e enviar essa informação para os clientes
- Guardar informação dos dados importantes na base de dados do sistema

Estrutura da classe `ServidorService`:

```
//variaveis
 + 8 variaveis 
 + de 12 HashMap //quase todos os dados estão relacionados key->value ex: clientex->outputx

//classes
```

[image: img1]
[image: img2]
[image: img3]

**Problema**

A classe está a ficar muito grande mesmo para mim, mas pensando no futuro de alguém precisar de alterar alguma função acho que vai ser difícil para ela dar a manutenção no código.

**Qual a melhor maneira de a refatorar?**

*Principais duvidas:*

- Crio outra classe tipo `ServidorService_2` e tento a dividir?
- Já tentei criar outra classes para apoiar a principal(ServidorService) mas estava com problemas no acesso as variáveis, qual a melhor maneira de fazer para a outra classe ter acesso as variáveis?  através de gets?

Comment: No momento que você listou 4 responsabilidades desta classe, você mesmo identificou no mínimo 4 novas classes. Para você gostar do seu código, cada classe deve ter uma única responsabilidade. Não faça `ServidorService_2` e  `ServidorService_3` pois isso não vai melhorar em nada o seu código (talvez piore). Para ter acesso às variáveis , sim, é através de `get`s. Mas você não deve publicar "variáveis" e sim "atributos" da sua classe (a técnica é a mesma mas o conceito é diferente e ajuda a perceber se o código está ok). Não vou colocar isso como resposta porque acho que é off-topic para o SO.

Comment: Independente do que fizer, **não crie ServidorService_2**!! Acredito que boa parte desse código deveria estar no Controller, outra parte do DAO com o BD local, outra no DAO para webservice (independente do nome que preferir dar para essa camada)

Comment: obrigado @Math quanto ao ServidorService_2 foi só um exemplo estúpido mas não sabia mesmo que outro nome poderia dar agora com a ajuda do @caffé e com a resposta do @Cold já tenho uma ideia de como fazer... Para mim o "Servidor_Service" é o meu Controller e nele sempre que preciso de algum dado, seja ele do webservice ou BD só tenho de chamar o método que está em outras classes: Ex: `new ProdutoDao().guardar(produto);` ou `listProdutos=getProdutosWebService();` é a isto que se está a referir certo?

Comment: @jsantos1991 que bom que já tem uma luz! Mas em opinião minha, eu faria a parte de acesso ao webservices fora do controller, em um DAO específico, eu inclusive tenho um nome para essa camada, mas não sei se é consenso, eu chamo de Resource. Talvez eu esteja falando besteira, mas é assim que eu faço e eu acho que atende aos princípios da OO.

Comment: @Caffé Obrigado só uma duvida, quando se refere a "variáveis" e sim "atributos" quer dizer que é errado dizer "variáveis" certo? porque o nome correto é "atributos" só para esclarecer o que disseste.

Comment: @Math sim como disseste e muito bem só tenho mesmo uma luz, logo nunca tenho bem a certeza se estou a fazer direito ou não, mas quanto a essa parte acho que está certo e felizmente, neste caso como não tem interface gráfica porque acho que é quando consigo destruir todo o mvc [mas esta parte já é [OFF-TOPIC]]

Comment: @jsantos1991 Não se trata do nome certo, o importante é entendermos que uma classe publica os dados que ela quer expôr, suas características e estado, o que pode ser um pouco mais profundo do que simplesmente aumentar a visibilidade de uma variável. Esse assunto é extenso, rende discussões úteis, mas inadequadas para este espaço.

Comment: @Caffé deu para esclarecer um pouco mais, mas ainda não consegui compreender como gostava, se poderes enviar um link|palavras chaves que fale sobre isso [EN ou PT] ficava agradecido.

Comment: @jsantos1991 não existe certo ou errado, existe apropriado ou inapropriado. O código deve ser apropriado para as suas necessidades, é claro que muitas vezes é difícil enxergar a médio ou longo prazo o que é o mais apropriado para você. Se seu software tiver vida longa provavelmente terá que refatorá-lo mais algumas vezes, e com experiência sofrerá menos nos projetos seguintes. Pra começar, tente nunca fugir dos princípios da OO mais básicos, como o da responsabilidade única (alta coesão) e baixo acoplamento.

Comment: @jsantos1991 São conceitos de Orientação a Objetos. Este link que achei agora parece bom: https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/ Esta seção em especial deve dar uma noção da diferença conceitual entre publicar uma variável ou atributo (quem garante as regas de negócio, como validação dos valores setados?): http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/modificadores-de-acesso-e-atributos-de-classe/#6-1-controlando-o-acesso

Comment: `(...)e algum código comentado para o caso de ser necessário no futuro(...)` Isso é mais tóxico do que urânio. Livre-se desse código. Se algum dia esse código se tornar necessário, vocês podem recuperá-lo a partir do repositório. Se isso acontecer, jogue na loteria também, porque uma vida de experiência com isso diz que código comentado voltar a ser útil é algo que ocorre uma vez a cada lua azul. E se não tiver controle de versão, parem o projeto até começarem a usar um.

Comment: @Math obrigado, no inicio é mesmo complicado saber o que é apropriado ou nao...

Comment: @Caffé obrigado pelos Links...

Comment: @Renan obrigado pelas duas dicas, a do código comentado que vou remover e a do controle de versão, que na verdade não estou a usar(tenho feito a mão), mas este projeto está na fase final logo num próximo sem duvida que vou usar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelas responsabilidades que você citou eu sugeria o seguinte (os nomes das classes são apenas sugestões, podes por ao teu gosto):

1 - Criar classes com a implementação de métodos específicos de acordo com as responsabilidades

`GestaoClientes.java` : Com a implementação dos métodos para tratamento da gestão dos clientes (Responsabilidade 1 e 3);

`AcessoBD.java` : Com a implementação de todos os métodos de acesso e interação com o Banco de Dados (Responsabilidade 1b e 4);

`AcessoWebServices.java` : Com a implementação de todos os métodos que interagem com os `WebServices`(Responsabilidade 1a).

**Nota:** *Responsabilidade 1a é "buscar dados a um webservice"* e a responsabilidade 1b é *"a uma base de dados"*.

2 - Manter os métodos relacionados e específicos do servidor na classe `ServidorService` e as variáveis (aquelas que devem ser visíveis ou modificadas por todos os métodos).

Se todas as variáveis permanecerem na classe `ServidorService` então acredito que os métodos nas classes que sugeri podem ser estáticos. E vais apenas invocando os métodos quando precisares.

Notei que tens também uma classe interna e ainda não percebi bem a ideia dela aí, porém não sei o que sugerir ainda quanto a ela.

Desse jeito acredito que já teras diminuido em muito as quantidades de linhas e facilitar a manutenção do código, pois o outro técnico saberia onde olhar de forma específica de acordo com o objectivo.

Answer (score 3):

A estrutura MVC indica você usar Model onde você irá criar classe referente a suas entidades dentro dela temos os atributos da classe e os get's e set's mais o `toString()` somente isso, se você estiver usando banco de dados você pode criar classes chamadas `DAO`(Data Access Object) cada entidade tem seu `DAO`, o Controller é para a regra de negócio ou seja cada entidade tem seu Controler, e a View é para a exibição das informações.

Você vai separar tudo em pacote exemplo:

```
br.nomeProjeto.model
br.nomeProjeto.controler
br.nomeProjeto.view
br.nomeProjeto.dao
```

Boas praticas dizem hoje que um codigo muito comentado não é bem elaborado se necessário crie interfaces e implementes seus metodos.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Espero não te ter confundido, mas a tua resposta nao responde a minha pergunta, a minha duvida NÃO é quanto a estrutura do MVC, eu falei em MVC e só para dizer que esta classe pertence ao controler, a minha duvida é quanto a REFATORAÇÃO...

Comment: @jsantos1991 como vc disse que essa classe já está no Controller, sugiro você seguir o princípio da responsabilidade única e criar um Controller para cada entidade, ou para cada entidade relevante, ou seja, algumas podem ficar de fora se o acesso a elas pode ser feita por uma dependencia de uma outra classe. Além do mais, alguns desses métodos não pertencem ao Controller, crie uma camada apropriada para eles.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que seria interessante você abstrair métodos que não estejam diretamente ligados a função de sua classe, tais como métodos utilitários, mas respondendo sua pergunta:

1. Se seus métodos estão ligados/relacionados ao que sua classe propõe não vejo porquê criar uma nova classe, claro cada um tem uma visão diferente do assunto;
2. É recomendado sempre acessar atributos de outras classes utilizando getters e setters, baixo acoplamento, e alta coesão.